# Ubuntu 12.10 w/ Kernel 3.7.0.7 and Open Source Driver RESUME/BRIGHTNESS CONTROL

Tags: 12.10, ati, xorg, power-management, brightness

I am using an Inspiron 7520. I got a AMD Radeon HD 7730m running in switching with an Intel 4000 HD. I have updated my Open source drivers with xorg edgers and x-swat. I am running on the kernel 3.7 and I am experiencing some problems that I am not having on the kernel 3.5. I get lower or upper my brightness, it is always stuck to 100% but I have nearly no brightness. My second issue is that my computer doesn't resume, it tells that there's an error and then it goes all black.

Also something that never popped me before when I was booting up. It says KVM disabled by bios.

Thanks for your help. Don't be shy to ask me for any additional details.

I have noticed also that even on the kernel 3.5, I receive an error sometimes when I resume.

Comment: Why are you using kernel 3.7? It is not recommended to upgrade kernels unless there's a specific problem which is solved with the upstream kernel. If there is no particular reason for using kernel 3.7, I suggest you uninstall it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concerning the brighhtness settings, do the following:

Enter your grub file as root:

`sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`

and edit the file as follows:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="splash acpi_backlight=vendor"
 GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_backlight=vendor"`

That should work, I also have switchable graphics on my dv6

*edit: Sry, I forgot that you have to update your grub file after editing it:

`sudo update-grub`